# Session variable lost after setting it in ajax call

Tags: 7, ajax, sessions

In my custom `.js` code included into administration panel via my custom module I have AJAX call:

```
... //call this on click or sth
jQuery.post("sites/all/...mycustommodule/ajax/here.php", function(result){ alert(result); }
```

And `here.php` defines some custom session variable:

```
<?php
sesssion_start();
$_SESSION['test_module_test'] = 'test';
echo $_SESSION['test_module_test'];
?>
```

When I hit `here.php` with POST request thanks to my `.js` code I get alert with session variable outputed:

> test

But then, when I try to `print_r($_SESSION['test_module_test'])` inside my custom module code, I always get some session variables, but without my `test_module_test`:

```
Array 
( 
    [views_seed_time-...] => 1482412682 
    [views_seed_name-...] => 1482412682 
)
```

I don't know if the session gets destroyed in between or there's something else going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd assume those are 2 different sessions; use `session_id()`in both contexts to confirm.

To make sure you're using the same session, just implement your AJAX path inside Drupal, with `hook_menu()`